# How to let back viewcontroller don't shrink when back viewcontroller present in another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to lock viewcontroller when i present another viewcontroller, like following image1.
I also change vc parameter modalPresentationStyle and not work to this situation.
And how to achieve this results?
Now I present viewcontroller also like following image2.
Have any parameter that I miss to set?

```
let vc = ExampleVC(nibName: "ExampleVC", bundle: nil)
var naviVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
naviVC.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet // any value not work
        
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(naviVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

image1:
[image: image1_perfect1]

image2:
[image: image2_bad2]

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? Do you mean you want to prevent the ability of the user to dismiss the presented view controller by swiping down?

Answer (score 0):

`.pageSheet` modalPresentationStyle is actually like your image2. By default, there is no way to make a presentation like image1. You must customize, these steps may help.

1. Create a controller (which has an X button on the top-right), with subViews[0] that is almost transparent (maybe alpha 0.5).
2. Make top-left-right of container content view rounded. Then add top padding with safe area or whatever padding you want. Leading, trailing and bottom should be equal to super view.
3. When presenting, change modalPresentationStyle to `overFullScreen`.

[image]